# MySQL Complex Inner Join Query getting error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Query Definition:

Select Students who have a grade of 85 or better in art

and 

who also have a grade of 85 or better in any computer course 

QUERY(explained in 3 sections is single query executed on MySQLWorkBench):

```
select Students.StudFirstName,Student_Schedules.Grade
from 
(Select Distinct Students.StudentID,Students.StudFirstName,Student_Schedules.Grade 
from (((Students

Inner Join Student_Schedules
On Student_Schedules.StudentID = Students.StudentID)

Inner Join Classes
On Classes.ClassID = Student_Schedules.ClassID)

Inner Join Subjects
On Subjects.SubjectID = Classes.SubjectID)

Inner Join Categories
On Subjects.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID

where Categories.CategoryDescription = 'Art' and Student_Schedules.Grade >= 85)
            As Stud_Art
```

Above code extracts Students who have a grade of 85 or better in Art

```
Inner Join

(Select Distinct Students.StudentID,Students.StudFirstName,Student_Schedules.Grade 
from (((Students

Inner Join Student_Schedules
On Student_Schedules.StudentID = Students.StudentID)

Inner Join Classes
On Classes.ClassID = Student_Schedules.ClassID)

Inner Join Subjects
On Subjects.SubjectID = Classes.SubjectID)

Inner Join Categories
On Subjects.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID

WHERE Categories.CategoryDescription LIKE '%Computer%' AND Student_Schedules.Grade >=    85)

As Stud_CS
```

Above code extracts Students who have a grade of 85 or better in Computer

```
On Stud_CS.StudentID = Stud_Art.StudentID;
```

Above code matches StudentID from Art and Computer

Error From MySQLWorkBench:

 
    Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Students.StudFirstName' in 'field list'

The above Query may be solved by SubQuery technique but i want to learn how is it possible with Inner Join technique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve Students.StudFirstName and Student_Schedules.Grade but your table aliases are Stud_Art and Stud_CS. Might that be the issue?

I think that the first part should be like this:

```
select Stud_Art.StudFirstName,Stud_Art.Grade
```

Comment: Yes you were right.I have corrected the first part.Then i also forgot to include Students.StudentID in both select query